# React native Flatlist onclick navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I used the flatlist to retrieved the data. Now I have no idea about how to set the onclick for my flatlist.

```
render(){
        const listActivities = this.state.activitiesList
        function Item({ title }) {
            return (
              <View style={styles.item}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
              </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.heading}>UPCOMING ACTIVITIES</Text>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <SafeAreaView>
                        <FlatList onPress={()=>navigate(DetailsScreen)}
                            data = {listActivities}
                            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.name} />}
                            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                        />
                    </SafeAreaView>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
```

I tried to use the onpress but it don't work. Does anyone have an idea about it? Btw i didn't used the stackNavigator but createDrawerNavigator.

Comment: You need to put that click handler on item, not whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which Item was pressed in `Flatlist` you can easily use one of `TouchableOpacity`, `TouchableNativeFeedback`, `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component available in react-native.

In you case you can do something like:

```
render() {
  const listActivities = this.state.activitiesList;
  function Item({ title }) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          console.log(title, 'was pressed');
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.item}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>UPCOMING ACTIVITIES</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList onPress={() => navigate(DetailsScreen)}
            data={listActivities}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.name} />}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

You can read more on [Official RN docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity)

On the side note consider declaring functions outside your render function for better performance in the long run to avoid redeclaring the function/Components again and again. like:

```
renderItem = (name) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => {
        console.log(name, 'was pressed');
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

render() {
  const listActivities = this.state.activitiesList;
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.heading}>UPCOMING ACTIVITIES</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <SafeAreaView>
          <FlatList onPress={() => navigate(DetailsScreen)}
            data={listActivities}
            renderItem={({ item }) => this.renderItem(item.name)}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add an `onPress` to the component **inside** renderItem, `<Item onPress={}></Item>`, which will set a state value. Then, when this state value changes, you can cause an effect like navigation change.

```
<FlatList
  ItemSeparatorComponent={Platform.OS !== 'android' && ({highlighted}) => (
    <View style={[style.separator, highlighted && {marginLeft: 0}]} />
  )}
  data={[{title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1'}]}
  renderItem={({item, index, separators}) => (
    <TouchableHighlight
      key={item.key}
      onPress={() => this._onPress(item)}
      onShowUnderlay={separators.highlight}
      onHideUnderlay={separators.unhighlight}>
      <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )}
/>
```

Taken straight out of the [react docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist.html#renderitem).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add onPress on the whole FlatList you can wrap it with a TouchableOpacity

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate(DetailsScreen)}>
<FlatList
         data = {listActivities}
         renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.name} />}
         keyExtractor={item => item.id}
         />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

if you want to add an onPress on each item:

```
<View style={styles.item}>
     <Text onPress={()=>navigate(DetailsScreen)} style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
</View>
```

or you can wrap Text with TouchableOpacity

```
<View style={styles.item}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigate(DetailsScreen)}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity >
</View>
```

Comment: for the second option, the View is put inside the flatlist or somethings else?

Comment: In the item component